# How to show edit button in datatable for limited number of records in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am displaying records using datatable. I am showing a edit & delete button for each row. But now I want to show edit/delete button only for first 30 records. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all define `rowIndexVar` attribute value  for `p:datatable`

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
```

Now you can achieve it client side using **rendered** attribute :

```
rendered="#{rowIndex lt 30}"
```

Since you are using primefaces button then code would be :

```
<p:commandButton value="edit/delete" rendered="#{rowIndex lt 30}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. You want the button to conditionally render, so confirm that you
   understand how to conditionally render a component (use `rendered`).
2. You want to only render the first 30 records, so confirm that you
   understand how to access the loop index.

Combine the two, and you have a working solution.

If you have any specific problem performing these steps that you cannot solve yourself, please feel free to post another question.

Answer (score -2):

I feel that your question lacks information but I'll try to be of some help..

You seem to be using JSF. Since you are using JSF you'd probably best solve this on the server side, in your backing-bean.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: My apologies, im new here. Indeed this was actually meant as a comment! Sorry!